# Why it's like this?

Tags: past-participles

> North of the Pyrenees Mountains, the natterjack toad offers a good example of hibernation, passing the winter ***dug deep into*** sandy ground.

I expect this sentence to be like this:

*North of the Pyrenees Mountains, the natterjack toad offers a good example of hibernation, passing the winter **by digging deep into** sandy ground.*

1-Is my sentence correct?

2-Why does the author use *dug* in the sentence?

Source:

1[- Google Book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Amphibians.html?id=0rZFAAAAYAAJ)

2[- Amphibians](http://toefl.kaomanfen.com/reading/exercise?id=11318&pid=11318&u=u1469372412018033&task_id=0&mode=reading) (Last paragraph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *telic* verbs—verbs which designate an action which ends in a change of state or position—it is very common for the past-participle form to be employed as a locative adjunct meaning "in the attained state or position".

In this case *dig in(to)* has a telic sense: the toad *digs* a hole in the sandy ground with the goal of positioning itself at the bottom. When it has completed that activity, it is *dug in*. Exactly the same expression is often used of soldiers in trenches:

> The troops spent a cold, pitiless Christmas **dug in** at Bastogne, until a successful counterattack turned back the German offensive. —[source](http://www.servingourvets.org/5-most-memorable-american-military-christmas-moments/)

Your rewrite is different: the present-participle form *digging* designates the activity of digging rather than the attained goal of the activity.

Comment: So, I can see it in this way: "The natterjack toad passes the winter dug deep into" . moreover, "Dug into" is a adjective. Am I right? And, in this sentence, "The natterjack toad passes the winter by digging deep into.", digging is gerund (and noun). Right? (I've gotten the semantic difference between these two.)

Comment: @AlirezaN. You got it. Participles are forms which act simultaneously as verbs and adjectives, a gerund is a form which acts simultaneously as a verb and a noun. *Into X* is a preposition phrase which acts as the complement to *dug*.